# MySQL: Selecting rows greater than a random number is producing strange results

Tags: mysql, random

Suppose one has a table of 1000 entries.  We want to pick a random number between 1 and 1000 and return all rows with an id greater than or equal to that value.  It appears to work just fine when entering a static value.  For example

```
Select * From myTable
Where id >= 500
Order by id Limit 10;
```

This returns the expected values of 500 through 509.  However, as soon as I try to replace that fixed value of 500 with a randomly generated one, things become very strange.

```
Select * From myTable
Where id >= floor(1 + RAND() * (1000 - 1))
Order by id Limit 10;
```

Suddenly, it no longer returns sequential values.  The values returned are also extremely biased towards the low end.  I get results like this:

```
65, 80, 96, 98, 112, 114, 115, 116, 130, 131
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: I noticed that, for some reason, if you replace `>=` with `=`, the results are no longer biased toward the lower end. I guess this is due to MySQL evaluating the rows sequentially from the first to the last, and randomly happening to match (`>=`) the lowest records first. This may also be related to the order by which the records were originally appended to the table, independently from their actual ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why your random changes....

```
  mysql> select id,rand() from test_big;
    +-------------+----------------------+
    | id          | rand()               |
    +-------------+----------------------+
    |          10 |   0.9478371384999129 |
    |          11 | 0.024267499357711057 |
    |   123456789 |   0.2778261120224615 |
    |  1234567890 |   0.3163280927728192 |
    | 12345678901 |   0.7481621585303565 |
    +-------------+----------------------+
    5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

the random is execute for each row.....but you can use a variable to solve your problems....

```
mysql> set @random:= rand();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @random;
+--------------------+
| @random            |
+--------------------+
| 0.7918265450669699 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id,@random:=@random+1 from test_big;
+-------------+--------------------+
| id          | @random:=@random+1 |
+-------------+--------------------+
|          10 |   1.79182654506697 |
|          11 | 2.7918265450669697 |
|   123456789 | 3.7918265450669697 |
|  1234567890 |   4.79182654506697 |
| 12345678901 |   5.79182654506697 |
+-------------+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

in your case make

```
set @random:=floor(1 + RAND() * (1000 - 1));
```

before the select function

Answer (score 0):

The random number in the `WHERE` clause is calculated separately for each row. So you don't have one random number to filter your results, but 1000 random numbers - one for each entry.

Answer (score 0):

Because the random function in the where clause gets evaluated every time and thus generating a new random number each time.